# String.Format Issue

Tags: c#

I want that string into String.Format But am not able to format that properly. Please if you can help me.

```
string s = "$(\"#container\").notify();$(\"#container\").notify(\"create\", \"basic-template\", { title: '{0}', text: '{1}'},{ expires: false, speed: 1000 });";
```

i want this into string.Format. I tried converting it but it shows me error . Input string was not in correct format

Comment: Try: `"$(\"#container\").notify();$(\"#container\").notify(\"create\", \"basic-template\", {{ title: '{0}', text: '{1}'}},{{ expires: false, speed: 1000 }});"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this working?

```
string s = "$(\"#container\").notify();$(\"#container\").notify(\"create\", \"basic-template\", {{ title: '{0}', text: '{1}'}},{{ expires: false, speed: 1000 }});"
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got `{` and `}` characters in the string that don't mean string.Format substitution. You need to escape them by doubling them up, `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: i tried but am getting error in string.

Comment: What error are you getting? Show us your updated code.